# Check box into value box

Tags: cognito-forms

Can this form builder allow me to have 3 check boxes, each check box (once checked) needs to have a corresponding value of £50 in a box 4. So if I check all 3 boxes then £150 will be shown in box 4?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

You can add values to Choice field items, but you cant set the values to add up into the 4th option in the Choice field. You can set up a Calculation field to add up the values outside of the Choice field.

You can also select to not show the price values in the Choice field if you would rather the end user not see them.

In the following screenshots you will see what the Choice field settings look like. Followed by what the Choice field looks like with the Calculation field set up under it, targeting the Choice field. The last image is what this looks like when active on the form for the end user.

[image]
[image]
[image]